# Custom redirect not working on the localhost

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect, url-rewriting, xampp

I have created a custom redirect in the .htaccess file in Magento root folder.
The base url of the magento is http://127.0.0.1/mymagento/

```
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^kit-rasage.html    /spray-can.html [R=301,L]
```

But when I access http://127.0.0.1/mymagento/kit-rasage.html it redirects to http://127.0.0.1/kit-rasage.html

The document root is as following in the httpdconf file

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Operating system is windows 7 and I am using XAMPP.
How to fix it?

Comment: What did you define your document root as?

Comment: @PanamaJack  Where should I check this?

Comment: In your vhost file. probably httpd.conf. Did you set this up?

Comment: If it's in the magento folder try setting the RewriteBase above your rule. `RewriteBase /mymagento/`

Comment: @PanamaJack Still it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following changes it worked for me.

```
RewriteBase /mymagento/
RewriteRule ^kit-rasage.html    /spray-can.html [R=301,L]
```

On local host we have other directories in htdocs folder so we have to add `RewriteBase /mymagento/` where mymagento is the directory name.